# Get all tip of business page

Tags: foursquare

I there is any way to find all tips and rating of foursquare page. i got auth token. but i cannot found valid url.
i am tring following link of foursquare

```
$redirected_uri=base_url()."feeds/forsqure_redirect";
$url="https://foursquare.com/oauth2/authenticate?client_id=F2RZ3WDTTR1HAHDPQAYOKLFURQGU3CYTLJKRZJPG3DHLFIBW&response_type=code&redirect_uri=$redirected_uri";
redirect($url);
```

but i cannot find url to fetch all tips of a business. can any body will told me please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make a request to our [venues/tips](https://developer.foursquare.com/docs/venues/tips) endpoint. It looks something like this:

```
https://api.foursquare.com/v2/venues/40a55d80f964a52020f31ee3/tips?oauth_token=YOUR_TOKEN&v=20130508
```

You may not even need an OAuth token in this case. You can simply make userless requests, where instead of an OAuth token, you pass in your client ID and secret. See our section on [connecting](https://developer.foursquare.com/overview/auth#userless).

Comment: i passwed my client secrate key in place of outh token but i cant got result.

Comment: Are you passing both your client id and client secret?

Comment: thanks octopi i got it and make function without using outh token.